# How to obtain a distribution of the unobserved time-invariant fixed effects in a fixed-effects regression?

Tags: distributions, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, intercept, plm

I am running a fixed-effects unbalanced panel regression using the plm package:

```
model_fe = plm(yield_diff ~ Bid_ask, data  = mydata.set, model = "within")
summary(model_fe)
```

**I am particularly interested in the overall distribution of the unobserved individual effects, i.e. the intercepts.**

I extracted the individual effects using the following:

```
fixef(model_fe)
summary(fixef(model_fe))
```

This returns the intercept (individual fixed effects) for each one of the individual. However, I am interested in the overall distribution of these effects (quartiles,  mean, median, max, min)

I seem to manage to obtain the mean as:

```
weighted.mean(fixef(model_fe), as.numeric(table(index(model_fe)[[1]])))
```

Is there a way to obtain the other summary statistics?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `summary` on `fixef` does not directly yield descriptive statistics as the commands together also report certain standard errors and p-values.

First applying `as.matrix` seems to do the trick, see below.

```
library(plm)
data("Produc", package = "plm")
zz <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
          data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))

FEs <- fixef(zz)
summary(FEs)
summary(as.matrix(FEs))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on this issue! I am able to get my descriptive statistics now, however, when I compare the mean to the weighted mean of fixed effects (which is supposed to be the overall intercept) called by
`weighted.mean(fixef(model_fe), as.numeric(table(index(model_fe)[[1]])))`
it gives different number than the mean computed by 
`summary(as.matrix(fixef(model_fe)))`
Does it mean that the summary function does not assign appropriate weights to the individuals? (my panel is unbalanced)

Comment: Quite likely something like that, yes. For my example, which is balanced, `weighted.mean` and `summary` return the same estimate. If you want to weight the individual estimates by the number of observations in each unit, weighted.mean seems better. I am not sure what the "correct" weighting scheme would be here, though.

Comment: Also take a look at the help page `?plm::within_intercept.plm`. Things get trickier in the two-way unbalanced case though.